# Why is my drive so full on my Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, sas

My server is Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server.

I have a secondary SAS drive where all my website files are with the following properties:

1. NTFS File System
2. Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties IS CHECKED
3. Simple Layout
4. Basic Type
5. Healthy (Page File, Primary Partition) Status

I have 3 folders on this drive:

Folder 1: 4GB

Folder 2: 2GB

Folder 3: 20GB

(These are the sizes of them when I click properties)

But the drive says it only has 10GB left out of 65GB. Why?  I'm trying to make more room on this drive.

Comment: Does the drive contain a lot of small files (e.g. significantly smaller than 4KB/cluster size?).

Comment: I would say there are alot of small files, like scripts, images, and stuff like that.. yea.

Comment: This might not be the sole reason for the missing space, but I expect it is at least part of it: When you write to a NTFS formatted filesystem you will almost always use 4KB of space. Even when the file you write is much smaller.  Think of it as writing to a book where you can only have one file per page. If you only need a single sentence then you will still use a full page.  Translated to computers this means than a thousand 2 byte files (e.g. txt files just containing the text 'no') would still use 4MB (1000x4KB) of disk space. Your situation is likely less extreme though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shadow Copies may be eating up your diskspace.

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage
```

Will tell you if it is.

Comment: this shows 0% full on shadow files or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Or the recycle bin / system volume information could be consuming space (both hidden directories on the root of the file system).

Comment: I've always found [Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/index.html) very handy for identifying this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try OverDisk. It's a great tool. Helped me to find out which folder is eating up my HDD space.

Hope this will solve your problem.