# windows server running on low disk space

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am facing one issue with disk space, Total disk space is 120GB, My files size is 42GB(including OS)

remaining 78GB should be free space but it showing low disk space.

Please check below images

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate https://serverfault.com/questions/423559/why-is-my-drive-so-full-on-my-windows-2008-server/423569#423569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Options -> View and uncheck `Hide protected operating system files`.

[image]

Your screenshot of C:\ doesn't show the pagefiles etc., so it is most probably enabled. After disabling the option the remaining files should show up and should be included in Explorers file size summary.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) to see a full breakdown of where your space is being used.